# Как реализовать выборку из таблиц, которые связаны «один ко многим»?

Tags: mysql, join, select, sql

Здравствуйте.

Имеются две таблицы в БД "`comments`" и "`answers`".

В таблицы "`comments`" есть поля "`id, name, comment, date`".

В таблице "`answers`" такие же поля, но есть ещё одно поле "`records_id`", которое является внешним ключом для таблицы "`comments.id`".

К одному комментарию может быть любое количество ответов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать запрос на выборку первых 10 комментариев и соответственных к нему ответов.

Задача усложняется также тем, что в результате запроса записи должны придти  в следующем порядке. Например:

- Комментарий 1

  - Ответ к комментарию 1
- Комментарий 2

  - Ответ к комментарию 2
  - Ответ к комментарию 2
- Комментарий 3
- Комментарий 4

  - Ответ к комментарию 4
  - Ответ к комментарию 4
  - Ответ к комментарию 4

Я пробывал реализовать это следующем запросом:"

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM comments 
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10
    ) AS comments
LEFT JOIN answers
ON comments.id = answers.records_id
```

"

Но тогда записи просто склеиваются.

Comment: древовидных результатов запроса не бывает. так чего вы ожидаете?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.name, t1.comment, t2.comment, t1.date  
from comments as t1
left join answers as t2 on t1.id=t2.record_id order by t1.date limit 0, 10
```

Comment: этот запрос вернут данные чуть хуже, чем в вопросе - будут взяты 10 записей, а надо 10 комментариев и столько ответов, сколько было (насколько я понял). а так разницы никакой.

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```
 select a.name, a.comment, a.date, b.name, b.comment, b.date
 from (select t1.name, t1.comment, t1.date, @n := @n+1 n
   from comments t1, (select @i:=0) order by t1.date) a
   left join answers b on a.id = b.record_id
 where a.n <= 10
 order by a.n, b.date
```

UPD: исправил ошибки, которые заметил (имена таблиц, алиас a не на месте)

Comment: А что означает символ "@" в тексте запроса и для чего он применяется?

Comment: Пользовательские переменные http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html